# In `timetk` ,the result of function `tk_make_weekend_sequence` show nothing

Tags: r, timetk

In `timetk` ,the result of  function `tk_make_weekend_sequence` show nothing . Anyone can help? Thanks!

```
library(timetk)

weekends <- tk_make_weekend_sequence(
  start_date = "2017-01-01",
  end_date   = "2017-12-31"
)

weekends
```

[image]

Comment: This works fine for me, maybe you should update the package, or it may be linked to your locale? Try to convert to date format with `as.Date` otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this you need to set an English environment for the `"LC_TIME"`

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")

weekends <- tk_make_weekend_sequence(
  start_date = "2017-01-01",
  end_date   = "2017-12-31"
)

weekends
```

Function `tk_make_weekend_sequence` uses a `lubridate::wday` function which work with your local language settings.

```
ret_tbl <- tibble::tibble(date_sequence = date_sequence) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(weekday = lubridate::wday(date_sequence, label = TRUE)) %>%
    dplyr::filter((weekday == "Sat" | weekday == "Sun"))
```

The problem is triggered by the `filter` in the last row. If you don't change `"LC_TIME"`, weekday will be the abbreviation of the day name in your native language.